# Display string as it is in HTML angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display log which is a long string in an HTML page. Sample log which I want to display is below.  When I insert this directly into my HTML, it is displayed as a continuous text. Is there any cleaner way of displaying the log as it is on my screen. One of the way to achieve is to replace `\n` with `<br>` but that would still remove lot of formatting like spaces etc. Is there any in built way  in angularjs or some kind of module I can use to preserve the formatting and display as it is?

```
Testrun log : org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"python Button sub components"}
Command duration or timeout: 62.06 seconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:595)
```

Comment: I believe an [html pre](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) should work. http://plnkr.co/edit/2uGe6zn7qHa628tVlxVE?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you just wrap it in a `<pre>` tag which will preserve the line breaks and spacing?

```
<pre>{{ logDataVar }}</pre>
```